# defining VirtualHosts in apache fails

Tags: apache, apache2

i tried using the vhost file (**httpd-vhosts.conf**) in apache to define different directories for different domain names. i defined it as follow and restarted apache.

no success - when i try to reach **www.domain.mx** it does not take me to the path mentioned in the documentroot.

i made sure the vhost file is included in the **httpd.conf** file and its module is loaded.

what am i doing wrong?

```
NameVirtualHost 12.12.65.90:80
NameVirtualHost domain.mx:80
NameVirtualHost www.domain.mx:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost 12.12.65.90:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@23.21.65.90
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName 12.12.65.90
    ServerAlias http://12.12.65.90/
    ErrorLog "logs/general-errors.log"
    CustomLog "logs/general.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost domain.mx:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.mx
    DocumentRoot "/taska/"
    ServerName domain.mx
    ServerAlias domain.mx
    ErrorLog "logs/domain-errors.log"
    CustomLog "logs/domain.log" combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost www.domain.mx:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.mx
    DocumentRoot "/taska/"
    ServerName www.domain.mx
    ServerAlias www.domain.mx
    ErrorLog "logs/domain-errors.log"
    CustomLog "logs/domain.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How do you mean "no success" One curiousity is that the IP based one has a dos based file path the other 2 unixy style..

Comment: @BugFiner i tried both relative and absolute paths - both were ignored

Comment: How are you accessing the server? is the server seeing your request as to "www.domain.mx" or, to IP x.x.x.x? by putting in the local hosts file this isnt always enough..

Comment: the idea i'm trying to implement is that when you access www.domain.mx you would be redirected by apache to /htdocs/taska/ and when you access it with the ip you would be redirected to /htdocs

Comment: OK, I can get that, but at the moment you havent answered how you're accessing the machine.

Comment: @BugFinder do you mean by which domain? www.domain.mx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently this is the way to do it (using serverAlias):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.mx
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/taska"
    DirectoryIndex taska.html
    ServerName domain.mx
    ServerAlias domain.mx
    ErrorLog "logs/domain-errors.log"
    CustomLog "logs/domain.log" combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/taska"
    DirectoryIndex taska.html
    ServerName www.domain.mx
    ServerAlias *.domain.mx
    ErrorLog "logs/domain-errors.log"
    CustomLog "logs/domain.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@21.11.65.90
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias 21.11.65.90
    ErrorLog "logs/general-errors.log"
    CustomLog "logs/general.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/taska>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```